# repetir video en java con libreria VLCJ 3.0

Tags: java

como se puede repetir el video una vez se termina de reproducir es decir hacer un bucle con la libreria vlcj en java en especifico estoy usando la version 3.0 aqui les comparto el codigo en el cual al parecer con el metodo .setRepeat(true); deberia de hacerlo pero no pasa nada si alguien sabe a que se deba le agradeceria bastante. en si se abre un Jframe que esta dividido para reproducir 2 videos a la vez hasta ahi todo bien si los reproduce pero lo que quiero es que se vuelvan a repetir una vez termina de reproducirlos se vuelvan a reproducir en el mismo Jframe

```
 package poolconexiones;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.windows.Win32FullScreenStrategy;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.x.LibXUtil;


/**
 *
 * @author hp
 */
public class MediaPanel {
   
    
 public void chargerLibrairie(){
             NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(
                    RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "lib");
            Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
            LibXUtil.initialise();
            
        }

 
       
        public MediaPanel(String[] args) {
            chargerLibrairie();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Omnibus Guadalajara");
            frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("autobus.png")).getImage());
            frame.setLocation(0, 0);
            frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLayout(null);

            Canvas c = new Canvas();
            c.setBackground(Color.black);
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 260);
            p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            p.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
            EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(frame));
            mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));
//            mediaPlayer.toggleFullScreen();
            mediaPlayer.setEnableMouseInputHandling(false);
            mediaPlayer.setEnableKeyInputHandling(true);
            mediaPlayer.prepareMedia("video.mp4");
            mediaPlayer.play(); 
            mediaPlayer.setRepeat(true);
                                  
            Canvas c2 = new Canvas();
            c2.setBackground(Color.black);
            JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
            p2.setBounds(0, 261, 1920, 819);
            p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            p2.add(c2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory2 = new MediaPlayerFactory();
            EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer2 = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(frame));
            mediaPlayer2.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory2.newVideoSurface(c2));
            mediaPlayer2.setEnableMouseInputHandling(false);
            mediaPlayer2.setEnableKeyInputHandling(true);
            mediaPlayer2.prepareMedia("video2.mp4");    
            mediaPlayer2.setStandardMediaOptions(":start-time=100", ":stop-time=150");
            mediaPlayer2.play();
            mediaPlayer2.setRepeat(true);
                              
        }
    
}
```

y aqui les dejo una imagen de los 2 videos reproduciendose pero al terminar solo se para y ya no lo vuelve a repetir.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

por fin despues de tanto tiempo logre hacerlo aqui la solucion para quien la necesite y se encuentre con ese problema en si era hacer un media list agregar los videos que se requieran y ponerlo en loop aqui les dejo el codigo para quien lo requiera ya que nunca encontre esa informacion pero leyendo la documentacion me encontre con esto aqui se los dejo suerte

```
package poolconexiones;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.medialist.MediaList;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.windows.Win32FullScreenStrategy;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.list.MediaListPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.list.MediaListPlayerMode;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.x.LibXUtil;


/**
 *
 * @author hp
 */
public class MediaPanel {


public void chargerLibrairie(){
         NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(
                RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "lib");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
        LibXUtil.initialise();
        
    }


   
    public MediaPanel(String[] args) {
        chargerLibrairie();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Omnibus Guadalajara");
        frame.setIconImage(new 
 ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("autobus.png")).getImage());
        frame.setLocation(0, 0);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        c.setBackground(Color.black);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 260);
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(frame));
        mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));
        MediaListPlayer mediaListPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newMediaListPlayer();
        mediaListPlayer.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
        MediaList mediaList = mediaPlayerFactory.newMediaList();
        mediaList.addMedia("C:\\videos\\video.mp4");
        mediaList.addMedia("C:\\videos\\video2.mp4");
        mediaListPlayer.setMediaList(mediaList);
        mediaListPlayer.setMode(MediaListPlayerMode.LOOP);
        mediaListPlayer.play(); 
        mediaPlayer.setEnableMouseInputHandling(false);
        mediaPlayer.setEnableKeyInputHandling(true);
                                         
        Canvas c2 = new Canvas();
        c2.setBackground(Color.black);
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setBounds(0, 261, 1920, 820);
        p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p2.add(c2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory2 = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer2 = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(frame));
        mediaPlayer2.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory2.newVideoSurface(c2));
        MediaListPlayer mediaListPlayer2 = mediaPlayerFactory.newMediaListPlayer();
        mediaListPlayer2.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer2);
        MediaList mediaList2 = mediaPlayerFactory.newMediaList();
        mediaList2.addMedia("C:\\videos\\video2.mp4");
        mediaList2.addMedia("C:\\videos\\video.mp4");
        mediaListPlayer2.setMediaList(mediaList2);
        mediaListPlayer2.setMode(MediaListPlayerMode.LOOP);
        mediaListPlayer2.play(); 
        mediaPlayer2.setEnableMouseInputHandling(false);
        mediaPlayer2.setEnableKeyInputHandling(true);
                  
    }
```

}